# How can I shift the last N lines of a file?

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu

I've a simple text file, named `samples.log`. In this file I've several lines. Suppose I have a total of 10 lines. My purpose is to replace the first 5 lines of the file with the last file lines of the same file. For example:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

Become:

```
line 6
line 7
line 8
line 9
line 10
```

In other words, I simply want to delete the first 5 lines of the file and then I want to shift up the last 5. I'm working on Linux. What is the most simple way to do this? Is there a command?
I'm working on a C program, but I think that is better to execute the linux command inside the program, instead of doing this operation in C, that I think would be quite difficult.

Comment: What if the file has more than ten lines? Or fewer? Do you always want to just remove the first five, or always just keep the last five?

Comment: (‘_better to execute the linux command inside the program, instead of doing this operation in C_’ a matter of opinion, perhaps, but starting a new process each time _might_ be bad for performance, and the risk of bugs _might_ be higher when constructing the command.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
tail -n $(($(cat samples.log | wc -l) - 5)) samples.log
```

You calculate the total amount of lines:

```
cat samples.log | wc -l
```

From that, you subtract 5:

```
$((x - 5))
```

And you use that last number of lines:

```
tail -n x samples.log
```

Comment: That's a [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat); the idiomatic solution is `wc -l <samples.log`

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
  tail -n +6 samples.log
```

will do the job. `tail -n +NUM file` will print the `file` starting with line `NUM`